# How to fix 'To sync this notebook, sign into OneNote'

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2016

The message 'To sync this notebook, sign into OneNote' shows on a yellow bar across the top of my OneNote application. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to fix this in the past by doing the following:

- Search for 'Credential Manager' via the start menu
- Click 'Windows Credentials'
- Look for 'MicrosoftOffice16_Data:live:cid=' and delete/remove it
- Sign into OneNote again

The error should disappear and the problem should be fixed.